# expect(...).toHaveAttribute is not a function - Why?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I created some basic tests and followed the getting started guide on Jests website, but toHaveAttribute is not a function apparently

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import { App } from "../App";

test("allows users to add items to their list", () => {
  const { getByText, getByLabelText, getByTestId } = render(<App />);

  const input = getByLabelText("What needs to be done?");
  userEvent.type(getByTestId("email"), "Hello World!")
  expect(getByTestId("email")).toHaveAttribute("value", "Hello, World!")
})
```

TypeError: expect(...).toHaveAttribute is not a function

```
  10 |   const input = getByLabelText("What needs to be done?");
  11 |   userEvent.type(getByTestId("email"), "Hello World!")
> 12 |   expect(getByTestId("email")).toHaveAttribute("value", "Hello, World!")
     |                                ^
  13 | })
```

I followed the tutorial exactly so im unsure why this is happening.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The method `toHaveAttribute` is part of [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) that enables to test DOM elements. You need to verify if you have setup it properly at your project.

Install the module:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```

After that you can include at your jest setup file like recommended:

```
// In your own jest-setup.js (or any other name)
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

// In jest.config.js add (if you haven't already)
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.js']
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an alternative where you use `getAttribute`

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/svelte';
it('should render avatar of user', async () => {
    const image = screen.getByAltText(`${MOCK_NAVBAR.username} avatar`);
    expect(image.getAttribute('src')).toBe(MOCK_NAVBAR.userAvatar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but easily solved it using playwright native getter - .getAttribute('someAttribute');

For example you can write something like that:

const locator = await page.locator('[name="SomeLocator"]').getAttribute('content');