# Checking for a class in React testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a class called `button-group` that is rendered like this:

```
<body>
        <div>
          <span
            class="button-group"
          />
        </div>
      </body>
```

Now, How do I check/query for the presence of the `button-group` class? I have written:

```
const { container } = render( <ButtonGroup /> );
expect( container.firstChild.toHaveClass( 'button-group' ) );
```

But this test is failing for some reason, thank you.

Comment: I think the write way is `expect(container.firstChild).toHaveClass( 'button-group' )`

Comment: gets fixed by this same answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/65948977/14409895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the proper ways for testing this would be as follows:

```
<div>
    <span data-testid="span-id"
      class="button-group"
    />
  </div>
```

And testcase as follows:

```
render( <ButtonGroup /> );
expect(screen.getByTestId('span-id')).toHaveClass('button-group') ;
```

We should not directly refer to the node for testing. Have a look at this doc as well https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-node-access.md

Comment: Thank you, I am trying like this:                                                                            ```test( 'should have ButtonGroup class', () => {
  render( <ButtonGroup /> );
  screen.debug();
  expect( screen.getByTestId( 'button-group-id' ).toHaveClass( 'button-group' ) );
 } );                                                                                                                               But Getting that `toHaveClass` is not a function:  
[Direct Link](https://d.pr/i/YXrT72+)

Comment: There is an issue with brackets. it should be `expect(screen.getByTestId('button-group-id')).toHaveClass('button-group');`